# Calling a program in for-each using a piped hashtable in powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I'm trying replicate the answer in [downloading-from-s3-with-aws-cli-using-filter-on-specific-prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301240/downloading-from-s3-with-aws-cli-using-filter-on-specific-prefix) using PowerShell. I tried using the method in [whats-the-equivalent-of-xargs-in-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428949/whats-the-equivalent-of-xargs-in-powershell#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20use%20Foreach,be%20helpful%20for%20nested%20objects.&text=Wow.,a%20native%20operator%20in%20powershell.), and have gotten close to getting the key name from S3 ls and passing it to a call command.

```
,@(Get-ChildItem -recurse | aws s3 ls s3://s3-bucket-name/year_2022/ABCDEFT-8D) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty syncroot |  Select-Object @{Name='KeyName';Expression={$_.split(" ")[-1]}} | %{&"aws" s3 cp s3://s3-bucket-name/year_2022/$_ .}
```

Although it iterates and gets all the key names in Select-Object but in foreach it ends up passing

s3://s3-bucket-name/year_2022/@{KeyName=ABCDEFT-8D-FILE1.XML}

s3://s3-bucket-name/year_2022/@{KeyName=ABCDEFT-8D-FILE2.XML}

And I get the key not found error. After searching around I tried replacing $_ with @_ but doing that passes the argument as
s3://s3-bucket-name/year_2022/@_

I have no experience in powershell and made it this far by just searching existing answers, but I'm not able to figure this one out.

For reference, if I run the powershell code without the call

```
,@(Get-ChildItem -recurse | aws s3 ls s3://s3-bucket-name/year_2022/ABCDEFT-8D) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty syncroot |  Select-Object @{Name='KeyName';Expression={$_.split(" ")[-1]}}
```

I get this:

KeyName

---

ABCDEFT-8D-FILE1.XML

ABCDEFT-8D-FILE2.XML

...

From what I could figure out, the output above is a hashtable and so I thought that @_ should work, but doesn't.

The powershell version is  7.2.5

Comment: I don't know aws.  Does this example help?  `get-childitem | foreach-object { remove-item $_ } `  The `$_` is what is piped in.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out. The first option removed all objects, hopefully the string works

Comment: Thank you @js2010 , this worked. Used the Foreach-Object to output a string. `@(Get-ChildItem -recurse | aws s3 ls s3://s3-bucket-name/year_2022/ABCDEFT-8D) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty syncroot |  foreach-Object {$_.split(" ")[-1]} | %{&"aws" s3 cp s3://s3-bucket-name/year_2022/$_ .}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of select-object creating an object, you want foreach-object outputting a string:

```
# return the last word
'one two three' | Foreach-Object { $_.split(" ")[-1] }

three
```